# Function only callable, if nothing else declared within script tag

Tags: javascript, html, ethers.js

I am experiencing unusual issues when trying to implement functions into html. After days of trial/error i narrowed the problem down. Whenever i am calling a function via button:

```
<button onclick="doAction()" >action</button>
```

It says the function is not defined, although it clearly is in my index.js file. I made sure it is imported correctly and the file is loaded in the browser.

Now, when i add another script tag to write the function in, it will only load the function, if there is nothing declared before.

This works (meaning it will read the function, but then fail because contract is not defined):

```
<script>
 const doAction = async() => {
            await contract.safeMint();

 }
</script>
```

But this will not:

```
<script>
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contractAddress = "0x000...";
const ABI = [...]

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, signer);

const doAction = async() => {
            await contract.safeMint();

}
</script>
```

It cant be a mistake declaring the variables and objects, because i dont get an error about that. Now i get "doAction() is not a function".

It gets weirder: when i comment the code above the function, it will still claim the function does not exist. Only if i remove it, it will call the function (but then throw because of the missing contract object).

Originally, i declared the functions in the index.js and tried to call them, having the same issue, which made me try it with separate script tags.

The functions itself have been used before in a react-app. Perhaps this is where the error is coming from? because ethers.js is not ideal for html/js ?

Regardless, this shouldnt affect the way a function is called. Even when the function only prints "hello world", i have the same issue, making it less likely that this is an ethers.js issue.

Comment: you're blowing my mind @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan so there's a quasi-global scope that the browser honors for outer-level `const` and `let` declared identifiers? (This is not something I've had direct experience with because of course I don't use attribute-based event handler assignment.)